# Stop IPython from changing terminal title

Tags: ipython

Starting with IPython 5, a IPython session automatically modified the terminal (tab) title. I prefer to set the titles of my terminal tabs manually. Is there a way to stop IPython from modifying the titles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be configured in the IPython config. If there is no IPython config file yet:

```
$ ipython profile create
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/home/user/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py'
```

In this config file you can set:

```
## Automatically set the terminal title
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.term_title = False
```